# A maximization problem of two variable functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is a two variable function and we want to find its maximum that is

\begin{align}\max_{(x,y)}f(x,y)\end{align}

where $(x,y)\in(-\infty,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)$. The right path, to find it, is to take the partial derivaves with respect to $y$ and $x$ and form the first order conditions (FOC) we obtain that $x^*=x(y)$ and $y^*=y(x)$ i.e. $x^*$ and $y^*$ are functions of $y$ and $x$ respectively. Then by solving the system of $(x^*,y^*)$ we have the possible solutions of the problem. To ensure that the function has a maximum we need to check the second order conditions with the Hessian matrixe, i.e. the concavity condition. Although, in my problem I have that the second oreder derivative with respect to $x$ is negative, i can not find the sign of the second order derivative with respect to $y$ and by taking the Hessian matrix I am not sure about the sign of the determinant of the whole $2\times2$ matrix. So another way to solve the problem is to find the $x^*=x(y)$ from the FOC with respect to $x$ and then to  substitute this in the function to obtain
$$g(y)=f(x^*(y),y)$$
and then I solve for (the equivalent problem)

\begin{align}\max_{y}g(y)\end{align}
In this case, I show that, since $y\in(0,+\infty)$, the function $g$ is increasing and concave with respect to $y$ and uniformly bounded from above, which means that in order to find the maximum, I must let $y\to+\infty$ (it has a supremum). Instead of finding an explicit solution of (x,y), I have sowhn that $x^*=x(y)$ and that $g$ which comes from the substitution of $x=x^*$ to the intitial function $f$ gives a maximum only if $y\to+\infty$.

My questions are

1. Is my reasoning in the right paths, since I can not change the restrictions that I have for my function, do I need anything more to complete my proof?
2. Has anybody seen any such approach of a maximum problem in any textbook or paper? I am trying to define it rigrously from a mathematic point of view.

P.S. I can not provide any mathematical formulas or solutions due to the complexity of the problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem and i have paused it. To put it simply for me there is a function $f(y)=-ay^2+by+g$, where $a\in(0,+\infty)$ and $b,g\in\mathbb{R}-{0}$ which is concave by assumption and my function $g(x,y)=\frac{y(x+c)}{d+2y}$, however the function $f\circ g$ can not be shown that it is concave, but in many plots in matlab it is obviously an increasing and concave function that seems to have a finite limit, i.e. it seesm also to attain the maximum when the variable $y$ attains the infite and in the same time the variable x is finite when $y\in(0,+\infty)$. So your problem is the soc.

Comment: Well, yes! I struggle in a same way with the second order conditions and i can not think of any other way to prove the maximum. But, in my case also the $x^*$ is finite with respect to $y$. I think that the proof is not wrong but it needs to be supperted by theory, but how since there is not a way to deal with the second oreder conditions. Of course in multivariate calculus we forget the definition application, since it is very hard to do this...